# What the federal government can do if a state or town became a dictatorship?

Tags: geopolitics

What are the federal options when a town or a state becomes a dictatorship or adapt shariaa law instead of its laws?

Let's suppose that the power take over was completely nonviolent and that the dictator used manipulation and that there's nothing unlawful.

Comment: It out the same as when any cult places itself above the law. Check out the branch Davidian (aka wackos from Waco) and fringe Mormon polygamist cults, and how they were handled.

Comment: Which 'Federal'? USA? Germany? Russia?

Comment: In US, federal and state laws take priority over town laws. Town can require certain color of roofs, but cannot require hijabs, or legalize stoning, or prevent people from leaving the town. But if some people choose to live on private land under the leadership of a certain person, it is their right. Look up Fundamentalist Latter Day Saints communities, and forced marriage investigations.

Comment: Since most (all?) dictatorships have a fig-leaf of democracy  and constitutional process, what **exactly** do you mean by "becomes a dictatorship"?

Comment: This may be an appropriate question for Law SE, or perhaps Politics SE, but as a Worldbuilding question it seems to fall into the develop-my-high-concept-idea-for-me trap.

Comment: I think a state under federal government cannot declare dictatorship as the government still controls that state. The only way this is possible is when the leader gathered his followers and created a population the size of a state, declared his dictatorship, on a unmapped location.

Comment: In reality.. all government's are a subtle form of oppression. Try not paying your tax. Of course.. in modern Western democracies the populace have come to expect some return on their taxes.. Just policing.. freedom of movement etc. But under all systems... There is nothing that will strip away the pretense faster than mass dissent. We think of the army as being there to protect us.. but in reality they are there to protect a very small subset of 'us'.. and the first thing that happens in any mass civil disobedience situation is army deployment.

Comment: Hello Ahmed.  I disagree with the reason your question was closed.  It would have been closed anyway as too broad and/or unclear, but [tag:alternate-history] is a valid concept here.  Are you willing to improve your question to get it reopened?  SE's Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  Give us a specific city to work with and describe with more detail how the shift in politics occured (as that would greatly dictate the nature of the response).  Then ask about how a specific aspect of the nation's political structure will respond (such as the U.S. Justice Dept.).

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this depends greatly on the type of federal government you're talking about. Two examples of federalism are Australia and the USA. Let's talk about Australia first.

In Australia, there is a restrictive (nothing is permissible unless explicitly declared in the Constitution) federal government, which is why the Australian Federal Government is constantly proposing changes to the Constitution that would go to a referendum. Ultimately, the states have final authority over their citizens, unless they have explicitly given up a specific right under the constitution.

In practice, this means that States cannot raise armies or other military groups, they can't levy taxes against the population (indirect taxes like stamp duty do however seem to be allowed) and relevant to this question, they can't impose any laws on religion. The Australian Constitution not only takes the power to do so into Federal jurisdiction, but it then forbids the Federation from doing it by saying that the Federal Government cannot legislate on matters of religion.

So, the state in question would not only be in violation of the Constitution, but so would the Federal Government if it tried to counter-legislate.

Fortunately, there is a remedy at law. By legislating in the manner you describe, the state would effectively have acted *ultra vires* (outside its power) and if called on it would literally cease to exist. In practice, what would happen is that the Federal Govt would immediately reinstate the state, but under new management so to speak and the offending enactment would literally disappear in a puff of smoke.

The US is slightly different and I readily admit to not knowing whether theirs is a permissive or restrictive federation, but in fairness there seem to have been a lot of American leaders who have been unsure on that point as well. But, as I understand it, there the states *also* have the supreme authority to govern as they see fit but the Federal Government has an overarching power as permitted by the constitution. What that means in effect is that because freedom of religion seems to be protected under the Federal Constitution of the USA, a State can't make the enactment you describe either.

One option for the state would be secession (withdrawal from the federation to become a nation in its own right) and then the US would have no recourse, other than to not recognise the secession and get into either a diplomatic or military dispute with the emergent nation. This is, in effect, what was happening during their Civil War, and why Texas is sometimes known as the 'lone star state' (but my history on the details thereof is not as detailed as this answer probably warrants).

In short, a federation is a central body made up of sovereign states that invest *part* of their powers into the central body for mutual protection and gain. If the regulation of religion is one of those powers the states invest in the federation, then there's a lot the federation can do. If not, then things can get...

Well, tricky.

It should be noted that a State is very different in this context to a city, county, province, local govt, etc. The difference between the relationships is that a State ultimately has sovereign power over the municipalities, but a federation only has power over the states that those states have agreed to relinquish at the time of formation.

Comment: nice answer on Aus and good memory on Texas - I happen to use the Texas case in my US based answer :)

Comment: In Australia you cannot change the constitution unless you put it up to a referendum. The government can't just change it as they want. Are you referring to legislation? Or are you referring to the fact that the constitutional changes have to first be passed through parliament before being voted on by the people and win a Majority in people and states to finalize the change?

Comment: @Shadowzee the latter. My point (and I'll edit to make it clearer) is that it's always the Federal government *proposing* changes that they want put to a referendum and that those changes would often result in a net increase in power to the Federation

Comment: What does Sharia law have to do with religious freedom? Nutcases like the Wahhabis aside, other than the head of state also being the head of the religion, there is no religious control in the legislative/judicial process. (The Iranians are included in the nutcases comment)

Comment: @nzaman I'm not convinced your comment is actually true. The point about Sharia law is that it is the secularisation of the principles of the Koran, and as such punishes activities that have nothing to do with the protection of the state but everything to do with the protection of the faith. Sharia law is inextricably connected to caliphates from what I've seen, (and the question refers to a dictatorship, furthering that assumption) but more than willing to review any examples you can provide where this has not been the case in recent times.

Comment: Per the 10th Amendment to the US Constitution, the US is technically a restrictive federal government; anything not expressly granted to the federal government in the Constitution is retained by the states. That said, some of those grants are *extremely* broad, like the "Necessary and Proper" clause - known as the Elastic Clause for how far it can be stretched.

Comment: @TimBII: Correct. Except, that the Caliph is supposed to be elected by plebescite, and was, until the [Umayyids took over by killing off anyone else who had a claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Karbala). Several laws were added thereafter, that described new religious offences, which conveniently could be applied to their political opponents, something that still exists today. [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_of_sharia_law_by_country) is pretty good at describing the current situation.

Answer (score 4):

There are still a few [company towns in existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_town) - so the idea of a person or company being able to build a community which becomes an incorporated municipality is certainly possible from a legal standpoint (albeit exceedingly rare in recent decades). Of course now that the dictator is in power, laws are passed or otherwise enforced which trample on the rights of citizens. Well, we have precedence for that too.

Looking at one of these company towns, Chickasaw, Alabama, which stopped a man from distributing religious material.  The basic argument was that as a private city it had no public ground (i.e. not a "public" sidewalk) and therefore the person in question was trespassing. When the case was heard by the Supreme Court they made two important (to your question) decisions:

1. Ownership of an area does not equal absolute domain (i.e. the more you open a property up to the public in general, the more your rights as an owner are going to be overtaken by the rights of those invited in)
2. That the rights of citizens under the Bill of Rights occupy a preferred position over the rights of property ownership

As this was a SCOTUS case, and has not been overturned by any new precedence (so far as I am aware) so any dictator in your story would have to deal with the legal repercussion of this. However, to build a case you would need a complaining witness/victim and it can be very hard to find people willing to speak up in situations like this (esp. when trying to corroborate a report).

---

Now, the above is if you have a "dictator" who legally claims his own township. If this is a violent coupe, rebellion, or even non-violent secession - we also have history on that. One of these was a bloody civil war, a more recent example [has been stated to have no legal standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_U.S._state_secession_petitions) due to a different SCOTUS case.

And the [decision in that case](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/74/700) has our answer on what would happen:

- Point 11: verifies the full authority to suppress rebellion and secession.
- Point 13: confirms the right of the Union (the Federal Gov. of the US) to establish temporary governance of the region.

So either law enforcement or military would step in to re-establish the area as part of the Union.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the US, the Constitution is pretty explicit.  Article 4, section 4: "The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government, and shall protect each of them against Invasion; and on Application of the Legislature, or of the Executive (when the Legislature cannot be convened) against domestic Violence."

Now that's not saying you can't have a de facto "dictatorship" that goes through the motions of elections &c.  There are plenty of examples in history: New York City's Tammany Hall, the Chicago machine, &c.  But even those have to take care not to be too blatant in their operations, lest various Federal agencies find them a juicy target for indictments.

As far as Sharia law &c go, the First Amendment takes precedence over any state or local law.